# Retrieve arrays based on the conditions met

Tags: php

I have a set of arrays. I wanted to retrieve the nearest date that is unavailable.

For example, I provided a date `01-05-2022`. The result I get should be the `room_id` 4 since it's the nearest date.

If I provided a date `05-05-2022`, the result will be `room_id` 6.

```
$array = [
   0 => [
     "room_id" => "1",
     "date" => "01-05-2022"
     "available" => "A"
   ],
   1 => [
     "room_id" => "2",
     "date" => "02-05-2022"
     "available" => "A"
   ],
   2 => [
     "room_id" => "3",
     "date" => "03-05-2022"
     "available" => "A"
   ],
   3 => [
     "room_id" => "4",
     "date" => "04-05-2022"
     "available" => "U"
   ],
   4 => [
     "room_id" => "5",
     "date" => "05-05-2022"
     "available" => "A"
   ],
   5 => [
     "room_id" => "6",
     "date" => "06-05-2022"
     "available" => "U"
   ],
]
```

This is how I did it but I don't get any results:

```
$nextUnavailableDate = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
  $selectedDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("01-05-2022"));
  $itemDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($item['date']));
  
  if ($selectedDate < $itemDate) {
    $q = array_filter($item, function($value) {
        return $value['availability'] === 'U';
    });

    if ($q) {
        $nextUnavailableDate = $q;
    }
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Any explanation is appreciated too as I'm still learning PHP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this one?

```
$nextUnavailableDate = [];
foreach ($array as $item) {
  $selectedDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("01-05-2022"));
  $itemDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($item['date']));
  
  if ($selectedDate < $itemDate) {
    // retrieving all the `availability` keys that has the value of U
    // will give you a list of availability value of U results
    if ($item['availability'] === 'U') {
        $nextUnavailableDate[] = $item;
    }
  }
}

// will then try to retrieve the first array since it's the nearest value that you requested
var_dump(array_shift(array_values($nextUnavailableDate)));
```